# Is there an accepted pattern for bundling MVC controllers and views in their own DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll

I'd like to bundle a controller along with everything it needs to function into a DLL.  It should --

1. Provide a controller
2. Automatically register a route for that controller
3. Provide a view for that controller to use

I want this to be as "hands-free" as possible -- if the DLL is present, the new route is available which is mapped to the controller and returns the view.  If the DLL is gone, none of this happens.

I can't be the first person to need this, so I'm curious if there are accepted/common patterns for doing it.

Comment: One version of feature you are looking for called "portable area". I.e. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698219/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-views-and-portable-areas and http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/06/mvc-portable-areas/ .

Comment: You could look at the code for nopCommerce - they have a pattern whereby plugins are shipped as a dll, which include registrations for the IoC container, routes, views, etc.